# Validity on my lecture note related to the concept of tree

Tags: discrete-mathematics, trees

On my lecture note, it shows the definition of the **tree which state tree is a *non-directed graph* and *does not consist of any circuit*.**

Also, in my lecture note, this graph, (as shown below) is not a tree.

[image: Example not tree]

So, my question is, is it really not a tree?, (or the definition of my lecturer has given is false, or I misunderstand the definition of the circuit)?

Comment: $adfa$ looks like a [circuit or cycle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycle_(graph_theory)) to me.  So it is not a tree

Comment: owh, I misunderstand the definition of the circuit then. I thought a circuit is a path that must go through all vertex and actually it is the definition of the Euler circuit. Thanks, @Henry

Comment: The definition in your notes should also say that the graph is connected, for it to be a tree.

Comment: Quite.  If we were to relax the requirement that the graph be connected, then it is instead a "*forest*", each connected component will be a tree.  Note that there are many other equivalent definitions for trees which you should see in your exercises shortly, such as a *connected* graph is a tree iff the number of vertices is exactly one more than the number of edges.